# How does a Linux network driver set the operational state

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working with a xilinx linux axi enet driver and in Linux the network operational state is showing UNKNOWN. I am trying to understand how a Linux network driver sets the operational state so that I can add the feature to the driver.  Can someone help me get a better understanding of how network operational state is set?

Thanks

```
Ip addr shows
eth3: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:0a:35:00:20:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.40/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global eth3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::80a:35ff:fe00:2022/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: "It depends".  There are a number of issues, including which specific version of kernel source and which build configuration options you're using. This is the first place to look: https://docs.kernel.org/networking/operstates.html

Comment: I'm using the xilinx-linux from xilinx repo. https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/tree/xilinx-v2020.1  using the axi enet driver in /drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx

Comment: Fine.  Please a) read the link I cited.  Then b) "grep" your source tree for some of the relevant variables/#defines mentioned in the article.  c) Be sure to "grep" through  *ALL* available NIC drivers, not just the axi enet driver.  For example, maybe a wifi driver will have what you're looking for, but the axi enet driver doesn't.